# Evaluate Integral $ I:=\int_0^{2\pi} \cos s \,\log (\sqrt{c^2 + a - 2 \cos s}-c) \, \mathrm d s $ for radially magnetized cylinder

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, electromagnetism

When trying to evaluate the magnetic scalar potential $\Phi_m$ of a magnetized cylinder (Magnetization $M$ in $x$-direction, height $Z$, Radius $R$, touching the $xy$-plane from below), I was able to solve two of the three integrals in cylinder coordinates, leaving one to give a completely closed form:
$$\Phi_\mathrm m(\rho,\varphi,z) = \frac {M R} {4 \pi} \cos\varphi \left[\int_0^{2\pi} \cos \tilde \varphi \log \left( \sqrt{\zeta^2 + \rho^2 + R^2 - 2\rho R \cos\tilde \varphi}+\zeta  \right)\,\mathrm d \tilde\varphi\right]_{\zeta=z}^{\zeta=z+Z}   $$
Now I'm desprerately trying to solve the remaining integral, which can be written in the form
$$ I:=\int_0^{2\pi} \cos s \,\log (\sqrt{c^2 + a - 2 \cos s}-c) \, \mathrm d s $$
for some numbers $ c:=\zeta /\sqrt{\rho R}\in\mathbb R $ and $ a:=\rho/R+R/\rho > 2 $. Transforming this into a contour integral around the unit circle then reads
$$ I= \oint_{\partial B_1(0)} (1+z^{-2})\log ( \sqrt {c^2 + a - (z+z^{-1})} - c) \, \mathrm d z  ,$$ but the various branch points for the square root and the log exceed my personal skills in arguing correctly about branch cuts and choosing a suitable integration contour.

Maybe someone could tell, if there is any hope that this integral is solvable in closed form, or if one is stuck with numerical evaluations? Solutions involving special functions (elliptic integrals / Bessel functions / etc.) are definitely no problem.

In my further attempts to aviod the difficulties with the complex $ \log $ function, there is yet another form (via substitutions), which might be solved by a suitable contour integration(?):
$$ I = 2 \int_0^2 \frac {\sqrt{1-v^2} \,\mathrm d v}{(\sqrt{c^2+a-2v}-c) \sqrt {c^2+a-2v}}  $$

Comment: Since the magnetization is in the $x$ direction and the cylinder is aligned along the $z$ direction, the problem is so symmetric upon reflection through the xy plane at $z=\frac{Z}{2}$. However, it doesn't look like your expression for $\Phi_m$ has that property, looking at the simple cases $z=0$ and $z=Z$ where the values should be equal.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $\Phi_\mathrm m(\rho,\varphi,z)=\Phi_\mathrm m(\rho,0,z)$, and I do not think that is the case.

Comment: @jwimberley: I'm assuming the cylinder's center (and thus also the symmetry plane) is at $z=-Z/2$, and my formula for the solution may be only valid for $Z>0$.
The log term arises from the second already solved integral, which read $$ I = \frac {M R} {4\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \cos \tilde \varphi \int_{-Z}^0 \left ( (\zeta-z)^2+\rho^2+R^2 - 2 \rho R \cos(\varphi-\tilde \varphi) \right )^{-1/2} \,\mathrm d \zeta \,\mathrm d \tilde \varphi$$

Comment: @davidh I beg to differ, as the $\varphi$-dependence is buried in the $\cos(\varphi-\tilde \varphi)$-term within the $\log$. It can be shifted to the $\cos \tilde \varphi$-term, by shifting the integration variable properly.

Comment: @LukasRauber Regarding the $\phi$-dependence, sure, but there would also be a contribution from another integral with $\cos s$ replaced with $\sin s$, of course, from shifting the definition of $\tilde \phi$, and I think David H was commenting on that.

Comment: Ah, I see now that you specified the column is touching the $xy$ plane from below, sorry.

Comment: One last minor comment about solving the integral in your comment: redefining the integration variable as $u = z-\zeta$, $d \zeta = - du$, with lower bound $u=z+Z$ and upper bound $z$, swap the new minus sign and the bounds to get
$$
\int_z^{z+Z} (u^2+b)^{-1/2} \, du
$$
Solving this gives me
$$
\left. \log \left( \sqrt{u^2+b}+u \right) \right|_{z}^{z+Z}
$$
which differs from your result by a factor of -1, I think?

Comment: The implication of the above being that the value inside the log is necessarily positive and this might simplify dealing with branch points. Even if I missed a minus sign, $d/du \log \left( \sqrt{u^2+b}\pm u \right) = \pm 1/\sqrt{u^2+b}$, so the integrand could always be put in this form at the cost of a minus sign.

Comment: @davidh Ah, now I see your point, and I stand corrected. Indeed, in the formula for $\Phi_m$ there was missing an overall factor of $\cos \varphi$. (I have corrected that in my post).
Yes, there is also a corresponding $(-\sin \varphi \sin \tilde \varphi)$ part; however, this vanishes for all \zeta: $$ \int _0 ^{2\pi} \sin \tilde \varphi f(\zeta, \cos \tilde \varphi) \, \mathrm d \tilde \varphi = \int_0^\pi \left ( \underbrace{ \sin \tilde \varphi f(\zeta, \cos \tilde \varphi) + \sin (-\tilde\varphi) f(\zeta, \cos(-\tilde\varphi))}_{=0} \right) \, \mathrm d\varphi $$

Comment: @jwimberley Yes, thank you for pointing that out. There was a missing overall minus sign in my formula for $\Phi_{\mathrm m}$. I instead have corrected the sign $\zeta$ within the $\log ( \sqrt \cdots + \zeta )$ part of the integrand, as suggested.
Also note that the argument of the $\log$ function is non-negative for all $\zeta$ (regardless of the sign), since $\sqrt{u^2 + b} > u \;\forall b>0,\,u\in \mathbb R$. Nevertheless, your observation may indeed help when considering the integrand in the complex domain.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the observation of @jwimberley, I was able to obtain a closed form sulution containing the three kinds of complete elliptic integrals. Contrary to my initial thoughts, contour integration is not needed; only for the last step I consulted a CAS (computer algebra system).

Is jwimberley pointed out in his comment, $\Phi_{\mathrm m}$ may be written as
$$ \Phi_{\mathrm m} = \frac {MR}{4\pi} \left[\int_0^{2\pi} \sigma \cos \tilde \varphi \log \left( \sqrt {\zeta^2 +\rho^2 +R^2-2\rho R\cos(\varphi - \tilde \varphi)}+\sigma\zeta \right)\,\mathrm d \tilde \varphi \right]_{\zeta=z}^{\zeta=z+Z}$$ for all $\sigma \in \{+1,\,-1\} $ (i.e. for both choices, the formula is correct).
By shuffling the $\varphi$-dependence out of the $\log$ and using the trigonometric addition formula, one has $$ \Phi_{\mathrm m} = \frac {MR}{4\pi} \sigma  \left[\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\cos \tilde \varphi \cos\varphi -\sin \tilde \varphi \sin \varphi  \right)  \log \left( \sqrt {\zeta^2 +\rho^2 +R^2-2\rho R\cos\varphi}+\sigma\zeta \right)\,\mathrm d \tilde \varphi \right]_{\zeta=z}^{\zeta=z+Z},$$ where the $\sin \tilde \varphi$ part vanishes in the integral due to anti-symmetry.
Integrating by parts and writing $a:=\rho/R+R/\rho$ and $c:=\zeta/\sqrt{\rho R}$ one gets $$ \Phi_{\mathrm m} = -\frac {MR}{4\pi} \cos\varphi \left[\int_0^{2\pi}\frac\sigma{\sqrt{c^2+a-2\cos\tilde\varphi}+\sigma c}\cdot\frac{\sin^2\tilde\varphi} {\sqrt {c^2+a-2\cos\tilde\varphi}}\,\mathrm d \tilde\varphi\right]_{c=z/\sqrt{\rho R}}^{c=(z+Z)/\sqrt{\rho R}},$$ as before valid for both choices of $\sigma = \pm 1$. Thus, as the crucial step, we can average over the two values of $\sigma$ and obtain
$$ \Phi_{\mathrm m} = \frac {MR}{4\pi} \cos\varphi \left[\int_0^{2\pi}\frac c{a-2\cos\tilde\varphi}\cdot\frac{\sin^2\tilde\varphi} {\sqrt {c^2+a-2\cos\tilde\varphi}}\,\mathrm d \tilde\varphi\right]_{c=z/\sqrt{\rho R}}^{c=(z+Z)/\sqrt{\rho R}}.$$
Now, by taking the integral only over the interval $[0,\,\pi]$ (compensated by an overall factor of $2$), and substituting $w=1-\cos\tilde\varphi$ in first step, and $w=2t^2$ in a second step, one arrives at $$\Phi_{\mathrm m} = \frac {MR}{4\pi} \cos\varphi \left[16c \int_0^1\frac {t^2}{a-2+4t^2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}} {\sqrt {c^2+a-2+4t^2}}\,\mathrm d t\right]_{c=z/\sqrt{\rho R}}^{c=(z+Z)/\sqrt{\rho R}},$$ for which an CAS gave me the closed form solution $$
\Phi_{\mathrm m} = \frac {MR}{4\pi} \cos\varphi \left[\frac c{\sqrt{c^2+a-2}}\left\{(c^2+2a)\mathrm K(m)-(c^2+a-2)\mathrm E(m) - (a+2)\Pi(n,m)\right\}\right]_{c=z/\sqrt{\rho R}}^{c=(z+Z)/\sqrt{\rho R}},$$ $$\text{where}\quad m=\frac{-4}{c^2+a-2}\quad\text{and}\quad n=\frac{-4}{a-2}\quad\left(\text{and}\;a=\frac \rho R + \frac R \rho \;\text{as before}\right)$$ using the closed elliptic integrals $\mathrm K$, $\mathrm E$, and $\Pi$ with the "$m$" argument convention (not "$k^2$").

I admit that I'm not able to explain or prove the last step (i.e. solving the last integral in terms of elliptic functions), but checking numerically, the solution seems correct. I'd be glad if anyone come up with an explanation (or perhaps even a shorter closed form solution). Still, it is my hope that the stated closed form solution may prove valuable for someone.

Comment: Clever trick, averaging the two choices of $\sigma$!